# Can I run website only with server IP without domain name?

Tags: .htaccess, server, dns, ip

Can I run my website `index.html` file without domain name and run it only with server IP and directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, just request it from your server: `http://<server-ip_address>/index.html`, where you replace `<server-ip_address>` with the actual IP address. So for example `http://192.0.2.34/index.html`, assuming that we are talking about an IPV4 address and that this address can be reached in the sense of network routing and firewalls.

This is only possible using the not encrypted http protocol, since https requires a valid ssl certificate issued to a valid domain name that matches the server's host name. Which is simply impossible here since that host name is the IP address in this case. Any attempt to use https will result in the browser blocking the request for security reasons.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work, I use http://<server-ip_address>/index.html but show me only: apache is running. I add another .html file and call it, but it's said: 404!

Comment: So that is your actual question ... This means that you either stored your file(s) in the wrong location or that your server configuration for that http host has a different `DOCUMENT_ROOT` configured which does _not_ point to that `public_html` directory but somewhere else. If that is a server you operate yourself than this most likely is something like `/var/www/htdocs` or similar. Check your configuration for the actual setting.

Comment: And the other way round: if that is _not_ a server you operate yourself but a hosted server then you can _not_ query it by IP address only. Reason is that the hosting provider needs to decide for each request _which_ content to access. That is done by host names ("domain name"). Without that information, using a generic address based request, no distinction between all the users hosted on the same hosting platform is possible.

Comment: "Any attempt to use https will result in the browser blocking the request for security reasons." is not totally true. You can go to `https://1.1.1.1/` and it works. Because the certificate has an IP address, not just hostname. Which is technically possible but should be avoided except for specific uses.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek That is a _very_ surprising claim you make ... To my knowledge a SSL certificate cannot be issued to an IP address. Which makes perfect sense. So could you please provide any evidence, any documentation, examples for the claim you make?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Ah, OK, I understand that you refer to the special "address" 1.1.1.1 _only_ . You should have made that clear in your comment, because that is totally irrelevant for the topic here.

Comment: "To my knowledge a SSL certificate cannot be issued to an IP address. " That is untrue. See "When the subjectAltName extension contains an iPAddress" in §4.2.1.6 of RFC 5280 and §7.1.4.2.1 of https://github.com/cabforum/servercert/blob/main/docs/BR.md ; besides IPs in certificates is used wildely in RPKI.

Comment: "Ah, OK, I understand that you refer to the special "address" 1.1.1.1 only " No there is NOTHING specific to that IP address, nothing special. Anyone can have a certificate including an IP address, based on the validation restrictions of the CABForum. So it is relevant because your assertion that it is not possible to use an IP address in a certificate is just false. It is not common, and for good reasons, granted, but not impossible.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Interesting, I did not know about that extension. And quite frankly I fail to see its purpose, which obviously is irrelevant. I learned something again, thanks for that. And I am sure that this excursion helped the OP a lot. Thanks!

Comment: It is not new (RFC 5280 is from May **2008**), but the case is not used often (and browsers had to be updated to handle the SAN extension properly), especially on the web. But certificates with IP addresses is used extensively in RPKI, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Public_Key_Infrastructure : "RPKI uses X.509 PKI certificates (RFC 5280) with extensions for IP addresses and AS identifiers (RFC 3779)" Hostnames can not be used there, because what needs to be secured is at the IP layer or below, where there are no concept of names.

Answer (score 0):

Search 'what is my ip' on google.

Install iis or apache on your computer and make your computer a server.

Specify in the program which files you want to make public.

Make the necessary port forwarding settings for the program you have installed.

Send your global ip address to the people you want to share your site with.

Comment: I don't get it! my files in a live server with a static IP, also I have directadmin and my files are in public_html, what should I do?

Comment: you should contact your telecommunications provider and get a static ip
because your global ip address is constantly updated.